# How to use tooltips on rectangle created by mouse movement - Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, events, tooltip

I am creating a rectangle with my mouse and i'm just trying to return info from the created object with a mouseover. I've been solving this with a messabox but there's just not many country to mouseover so the number of popup can be monstrous.

I decided to use a tooltip. Thing is it's not working on my mouse over :

```
       JTextField text = new JTextField();
    if (coordX > coordXRec && coordX < coordXRec + width && coordY > coordYrec && coordY < coordYrec + height){
        text.setToolTipText(i.GetInfoPays());
        text.getToolTipText();
}
```

Naturally, i want it to show when i mouseover my rectangle created :

[That green rectangle was made by the user so i can't 'preset' an event
or use it as a panel for my tooltip.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGwm8.png)

[This is what excepted, but using a tooltiptext, not a messabox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5WuQ.png)

I've been using a MouseEventMoved to know if im hovering over my rectangle. Its working but i'm stuck at sort of changing my messagebox into a tooltip.

Answer (score 5):

Use `setToolTipText("...");` with the appropriate `String` when needed (e.g. during `paintComponent()`).

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.util.*;

public class MouseShapeDetection {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    MouseShapeDetection() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        
        ui.add(new ShapePanel());
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            MouseShapeDetection o = new MouseShapeDetection();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class ShapePanel extends JPanel {

    Point point = new Point(0, 0);
    Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(600, 300);
    ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    Color translucent = new Color(0,0,255,87);
    Color selectedColor = Color.GREEN;
    Color unselectedColor = Color.RED;

    public ShapePanel() {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MotionListener());
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Random r = new Random();
        int x, y, w, h, wP = preferredSize.width, hP = preferredSize.height;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 40; ii++) {
            w = r.nextInt(100)+40;
            h = r.nextInt(50)+20;
            x = r.nextInt(wP - w);
            y = r.nextInt(hP - h);
            Ellipse2D.Double ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
            shapes.add(ellipse);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Shapes: ");
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        for (int ii=0; ii<shapes.size(); ii++) {
            Shape shape = shapes.get(ii);
            g2.setColor(translucent);
            g2.fill(shape);
            if (shape.contains(point)) {
                g2.setColor(selectedColor);
                sb.append(ii);
                sb.append(" ");
            } else {
                g2.setColor(unselectedColor);
            }
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.5f));
            g2.draw(shape);
        }
        setToolTipText(sb.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return preferredSize;
    }

    class MotionListener extends MouseMotionAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            point = e.getPoint();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please accept it by clicking the 'tick' mark to the left of it. If not, an explanation would be helpful. Questions with accepted answers are prioritised in search results, allowing people to find solutions more easily.